# Kendo AngularJS module fails to load in custom Ektron widget

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, ektron

I'm experiencing problems when trying to load an AngularJS module in a custom Ektron widget. The app.js file starts with:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'kendo.directives', 'chieffancypants.loadingBar']);
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module kendo.directives due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'kendo.directives' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Now, I'm pretty sure I've not misspelled it and the Kendo JavaScript file is loaded so not sure what's going on. Like the best of issues it's an intermittent one, it only happens on some pages and only some of the time, and I can't yet see any pattern in either the affected pages or the times it occurs.

Here's the script files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/js/kendo/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/js/kendo/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/js/kendo/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/js/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/js/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/js/app.js"></script>
```

Cheers,
Stuart.

Answer (score 0):

Ektron may also be loading it's own jQuery library file.  I would check in the HTML source of the page to see if you are getting more than 1 jQuery library loaded.  When this happens it usually breaks most of the Javascript on the page.

It is also worth checking the Chrome Console or Firefox's Web Developer toolbar plugin to see what Javascript errors are thrown.  You might be getting earlier errors in Javascript which has a knock on effect here.

Comment: Ektron absolutely does load it's own jQuery library although we've been assured that it shouldn't clash if we want to use another version. So far it hasn't.

Comment: There are no other errors logged in the Chrome or Firefox consoles.